# Pointers from c++ to OpenCL

Tags: c++, pointers, opencl

Basicly, i have a struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct *foo[8];
}
```

Now (how) can I load this up to the OpenCL memory? Will c++ pointers be valid in OpenCL and are they pointing to the object they used to on CPU-Level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer is relevant on the memory where it is used.

An OpenCL device has its own memory, then an address from host memory differs from the device memory.

You have to transfer your data in a buffer then pass the buffer to the kernel(s).

This post could interest you : [passing array of structs to the kernel in open CL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532441/passing-array-of-structs-to-the-kernel-in-open-cl)

Comment: Any idea, how I could possibly load this kind of struct into OpenCL? I'll have to use pointers there, since it is recursive.

Comment: Beware of performance: Non-contiguous access, as those potentially caused by pointer arithmetic, are very slow in most accelerators.

Comment: @Addi you can flatten your recursive structure in an array and point to other struct using their indexes. Or you can have two arrays, one for your structs the seconds for the relations between them.